# How to deal with JVM OutOfMemoryError on Linux?

Tags: java, memory, crash, jvm, memory-leaks

Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.4 32-bit + Sun HotSpot JVM 6u5 32-bit + JVM settings`-Xms1536m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`.

The JVM crashes with the following errors:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 828752 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
>   Internal Error (allocation.cpp:218), pid=21557, tid=329534352
>   Error: Chunk::new
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 383504 bytes for GrET in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_05/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
>   Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:42), pid=16927, tid=334281616
>   Error: GrET in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_05/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 256000 bytes for GrET in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_05/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
>   Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:42), pid=16863, tid=334216080
>   Error: GrET in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_05/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/growableArray.cpp
>   ..........

It may be the JVM itself C/C++ core memory leak, the C/C++ memory usage reaching the JVM critical value, or the platform swap space is insufficient.

How to deal with JVM itself C/C++ core memory leak?
Valgrind v3.7 cannot work with the hotspot JVM 6u5.

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6423256

Answer (score 0):

The JVM crash here is just mislaeading. The problem is that the process runs out of address space. Your "-Xmx2048m" is simply too big for the current available virtual memory and/or specific 32bit O/S in general.

Under 32-bit Windows any process can only address up to ~1.6GB RAM. 
Others OS depends. Linux should be able to use ~3GB max.

On top of your object heap size (-Xmx) the JVM needs some further RAM for stack, object management, gc structures, etc. In practice this leads on 32-bit Windows systems to a maximum heap size around 1100MB.

For more details about the process memory size limit see for example tis blog post: https://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2007/03/04/32-bit-windows-and-jvm-virtual-memory-limit

Comment: Are you speaking about Java processes specifically or about all processes in general when telling that `A 32bit process can only address up to ~1.6GB RAM`?

Comment: In fact I mixed things up. 1,6GB applies only to Windows and in fact this applies to processes in generally. On other OS like Linux, BSD and so one it differs. I'll update my (misleading) response.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says, that your JVM could not allocate further memory. The available (physical) memory is 0 so your system is using the swap. Then at some point, the swap will full of swapped memory pages and further request for memory (alloc) will therefore fail.

Test the usage of your swap with

```
$ swapon -s 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/xvda2              partition   8386556 99312   -1
```

You can increase the swap size at any time. [See this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/348052/how-to-increase-swap-size)